# React Router `history` and `location` mismatched after back button

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux, connected-react-router

In my React app, after navigating from Home to a child page and then hitting the back button, React `<Router>` shows a mismatched location in it's internal state vs the props it's passed from `history` and the incorrect `<Route>` is displayed for the currently shown URL in the address bar

The contents of the `<Route>` do change; data gets updated by the location change Redux action. The displayed `<Route>` shows new data, but it's the wrong `<Route>`.

The basic structure of the app is:

```
<Root>                                  (custom)
  <Provider>                            (react-redux)
    <ConnectedRouter>                   (connected-react-router)
      <App>                             (custom)
        <Switch>                        (react-router-dom)
          <Route path="/" exact />      (react-router-dom)
          <Route path="/quality:q" />   (react-router-dom)
```

Initially we navigate to root and `<Route path="/>` is correctly displayed. We click a link that correctly takes us to `<Route path="/quality/:q" />`. From there we hit browser back, the URL changes to `/` but `<Route path="/quality:q" />` is still displayed, but it shouldn't be anymore.

Redux devtools show this rendered tree, which I'm including a few of the key components added by those we've used explicitly.

```
<Root>                                  (custom)
  <Provider>                            (react-redux)
    <ConnectedRouter>                   (connected-react-router)
      <Router>                          (injected)
        <Context.Provider>              (injected)
          <App>                             (custom)
            <Switch>                        (react-router-dom)
              <Route path="/" exact />      (react-router-dom)
              <Route path="/quality:q" />   (react-router-dom)
```

When in this incorrect state, everything up to `<ConnectedRouter>` is correct. `<ConnectedRouter>` has a single prop which is `history` that has the correct location, the root.

The `<Router>` immediately below it is mismatched. It has a `history` prop that is ok, but it has a stale `location` in state that shows the old url.

When the bad location data is context passed to the `<Route>`s they get the path to check against from their `location` prop which match's `<Router>`'s stale state. As a result, the wrong `<Route>` is rendered.

I can't figure out what I did to cause this mismatch. It's all straightforward routes and uses `<Link>` components for all links from home to the child pages and back.

Has anyone seen this before and/or can point me in the direction as how to resolve this problem?

[image: Screenshot of mismatched props and state]

Comment: I am facing a similar issue where history.location is correct but location isn't , were you able to figure out the cause?

Answer (score 2):

I think your routing structure needs to be refactored because of how you're attempting to match against (possibly nested) URLs.

If you want `/quality/:id` to fall underneath `/`, then the `Route` needs to be a child of the `component`.

For example, the `Route` would be:

```
<Route path="/" component={Home} />
```

Then inside the `Home` component, you'll have child `Route`s that use `match.url` ([route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match)) as a string matcher:

```
const Home = ({ match: { url } }) => (
 <>
  <div>Home<Home>
  <Switch>
    <Route path={`${url}quality/:q` component={Quality} />
    <Route path={`${url}some/other/route`} component={Example} />
  </Switch>
 </>
);
```

However, if you want the opposite, where `/` is independent of `/quality/:p`, then you'll need to use `exact`:

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
   <Route exact path="/quality/:p" component={Quality} />
   <Route exact path="/some/other/route" component={Example} />
<Switch>
```

---

**Working example**

In this example, `/home`, `/about` and `/dashboard` are separate routes from each other; however, `/dashboard` is a parent to these child routes: `/dashboard/settings` and `/dashboard` (order is important!) and `/dashboard` renders a `Dashboard` component that also happens to be a parent to a `/dashboard/profile` child route! Order and `exact` are important to how each nested route will be rendered. I've also included a `goBack` example inside `pages/Profile` to demonstrate that `connected-react-router`'s history maintains consistency with `react-router-dom` Route history routing.

[demo](https://ocsbe.csb.app/)

[source](https://codesandbox.io/s/connected-react-router-ocsbe)

---

If you're following the above convention, then the only other problem would be that `react-hot-loader` is preventing state changes. I personally don't use RHL because I find it to be rather buggy, but to each their own. That said, I've used `connected-react-router` for the past 3 or 4 of my projects and I've never had props/state mismatch (other than having some shared redux data that was stale and needed to be reset before loading another component that was reusing the same data structure).

Comment: Thank you for the response. In abbreviating the message for posting I left out the `exact` keyword on the root route but it is there in the original code. I updated the question to clarify.

Comment: If you can create a reproducible codesandbox demo (doesn't need to be fancy), then it'll be easier to help. Otherwise, it's a guessing game.

Comment: agreed, if I could recreate I could probably track it down. I'm reverting and reapplying the changes since last known working version line by line to see what is causing this.

Comment: Another thing to consider is if you're using a service worker, then it may be caching your requests.

Comment: @SamuelNeff - did you ultimately fix this? If so, what was the fix?

Comment: @Ben, unfortunately I don't remember. I'm not at that job anymore so I can't look it up. If there was a single solution, I would have posted it back here. Most likely I started the PR over, applied things step by step, and it worked that time, 'cause programming sometimes is just sensitive. I wish I had a better answer for you.

Comment: Gotcha, I will note that I was able to fix this exact issue for myself by ripping out connected-react-router. Not the simplest solution but it did work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use react-router 5+, You can pass location from upper scope into Switch. I pass from history context. It fixes the same problem in my case

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. It turned out that I had a `PureComponent` somewhere in my tree that was causing it. Using `withRouter` and passing the `location` into the `PureComponent` fixed the issue.

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const App = withRouter(({ location, children }) => (
  <IntlProvider location={location}>
    {children}
  </IntlProvider>
));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Root>
    <Provider>
      <ConnectedRouter>
        <App>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact />
            <Route path="/quality:q" />
          </Switch>
        </App>
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
  </Root>
```